# Is there a central repository that states a country's latest policy on bitcoin?

Tags: legal, bitcoin-economy, politics

The legal status of bitcoin changes from country to country, to include a wide range of policies from acceptance to outright banning it.

Answer (score 2):

The best I found so far is Wikipedia. It is actually quite up to date.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_bitcoin_by_country

Comment: Hello Tagir, please feel free to put personal information or references to your company into your user profile, but please do not mention your business in posts completely unrelated to your business. Thank you.